# Get currency symbol aka localeconv() in ColdFusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, numbers, string-formatting, currency

I'm doing some javascript work inside a ColdFusion shopping cart, and I need to be able to format some numbers in js which will mimic LScurrencyFormat() in CF.

Currently we are taking the first (left,1) character of a formatted string but that doesn't work for currencies like Yen or Euro which come after the number, not to mention any multiple character currency symbols.

What I need to find, based on the current CF locale, is

- currency symbol
- decimal delimiter (, or .)
- leading or trailing (before or after the number)

From there i can run my own js formatting to make the formatted numbers come out as expected on the page.In php we can use localeconv() to get these values... how can I find them in CF?

Comment: Most online shops deal only in one currency and leave conversion to other currencies up to whatever payment service the user choses. Visitors may not want to use the currency or conventions of the geographic location they are in, so don't presume they do. Just make it clear what currency and conventions are being used by the site and leave the rest to the visitor.

Comment: Rob - thanks but we're already past that point in this particular app. Just need to fill in these specific blanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any built in functions. However, you can obtain the first two items from java. As far as the third, the closest suggestion I have seen is to [parse](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=137963) the [localized number pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10464_05/integrate.904/b12121/trans_funct.htm#g654533) and detect the position of the currency *sign* ie \u00A4. Note: It is just a mask placeholder. It is **not** the same as the actual currency symbols like "$" or "£".

**Edit:**
As discussed in the comments, getLocale() returns some user friendly name which unfortunately does not quite line up with java's. The easiest way to get the java locale object for the current `request` is using getPageContext().getResponse().getLocale().

```
<cfscript>
    // Get the current locale as a java object 
    javaLocale = getPageContext().getResponse().getLocale();

    // get numeric settings for that locale
    currency = createObject("java", "java.text.DecimalFormat").getCurrencyInstance(javaLocale);
    symbols = currency.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

    // 164 => decimal code point for currency sign 
    currencyPattern = currency.toLocalizedPattern();
    result.hasTrailingCurrencySymbol = currencyPattern.indexOf(javacast("int", 164)) > 0;
    result.currencySymbol = symbols.getCurrencySymbol();
    result.decimalSeparator= symbols.getDecimalSeparator();

    WriteDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - using DecimalFormatSymbols, I am able to parse out the required values to some extent, with a few remaining issues: 

- many of the locales return the strange symbol "¤" as the currency symbol

- java locale codes aren't the same as ColdFusion , and many locales that exist in CF don't necessarily seem to be available in Java

So, this gets me close, but... not close enough yet for what we need.

Also, I am having a hard time getting the current Locale code in Java. (i.e. java version of CF's GetLocale() - probably a syntax error, but I can't seem to find the right output.

Comment: I am able to use getDefault().getLanguage() (or other methods below getDefault() ) to return the current server_default_ locale, but I don't see where I can get the application-specified locale. As noted if I use CF's #getLocale()# , the result is a different format and syntax than the java locale codes. Maybe i'm trying to mix apples and oranges here but it doesn't seem like it should be this difficult.

Comment: I believe the only way to access the locale of the current `request` is through getLocale(). Unfortunately it returns some user friendly string that does not *quite* line up with java locale names. I am not sure why they chose to do that. There may be a simpler option, but you could create a structure that maps those values to the ISO country/language codes or a Locale object representing those codes. Then do a lookup. Re: *strange currency symbol* that is not the currency symbol. It is a placeholder for where the actual symbol will appear.

Comment: See my updated example and explanation of currency signs and translating getLocale()

Comment: You nailed it. 
The use of CFLocaleMgr is genius and 
currencyPattern = currency.toLocalizedPattern(); 
is the key I was crucially missing.

As for the 'strange currency symbol', I explored the links in your original answer after posting, and saw that it was some kind of placeholder, but by that time my head was too full of trial-and-error to respond again.

What you have added here is perfect, and I have my little system working exactly the way we wanted. 

Again, thank you Leigh, and thanks StackOverflow!

Comment: {smack} I do not know what I was thinking. I just remembered the simplest way to get the locale is using: `getPageContext().getResponse().getLocale()` Much easier and no need to mess around with internal classes ;) I will update the example.

Answer (score 1):

getLocale() returns the old cf5 style locale "names" but only for those locales supported by cf5. if you dump out the supported locales (Server.Coldfusion.SupportedLocales) you'll see the goofy old cf5 style locale names as well as the core java locale IDs (ie both "Chinese(China)" and "zh_CN"). if your locale wasn't one of the cf5 supported locales you should see the core java locale ID (ie th_TH for thai, thailand). see

http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=82474

as a small tweak to leigh's answer, you should also be concerned with the currency/locale's fraction digits. for instance in normal practice, you can't have part of a yen (ie 1.1 isn't quite kosher). you can get that info from the Currency class's getDefaultFractionDigits() method:

```
result.fractionDigits=currency.getDefaultFractionDigits();
```

Comment: Ah, that explains the weird "names". It happened pre-java. +1, Good point about fraction digits.